# Enforce prop should be either of two functional components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-functional-component, react-proptypes

I want to enforce a prop should be one of two different components, basically this:

```
MyComponent.propTypes {
      propA: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.instanceOf(ClassComponentA)
        PropTypes.instanceOf(ClassComponentB)
      ]),
}
```

The problem with this is it only works if `ClassComponentA` and `ClassComponentB` both are class components. How can I make it work when `ClassComponentA` and `ClassComponentB` are both functional components? The solution doesn't have to use [PropTypes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types).

Comment: If you're open to using typescript, you could define it in an interface

Comment: @LiorPollak Please show how to in an answer

Answer (score 0):

Well, a functional component is just a function that receives props and returns a JSX Element.

So you could do something like the following:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const Demo = ({ n }) => <div>{n}</div>;

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello {this.props.name}</h1>
        {this.props.customProp}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  customProp: function (props, propName, componentName) {
    // Here you can assert that props[propName].props are the ones you expect
  }
};

if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  render(
    <App name="World" customProp={<Demo n={5} />} />,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
}
```

In typescript, it could be a little more simple (in my opinion):

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { ReactElement } from "react";

type C1Props = { n: number };
type C2Props = { a: number };

const C1 = ({ n }: C1Props) => <div>{n}</div>;
const C2 = ({ a }: C2Props) => <div></div>;

const Demo = ({ propA }: { propA: ReactElement<C1Props> | ReactElement<C2Props> }) => (
  <div>Hello {propA}</div>
);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Demo propA={<C1 n={5} />} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

EDIT: Better typescript version

Comment: Your typescript version is not a solution because ANY component whose props is the union of `C1Props` and `C2Props` can be given as a prop.

Comment: I've edited and fixed it

Comment: Assume `interface C1Props { text: string; }`, then now you can give as a prop to `Demo` ANY component who takes exactly one prop named text that is of type string, but I would like to be so that you can only pass either of `C1` and `C2` to Demo. So, still, not quite. It's too lax.

Comment: Hmm, you are correct on that one. I guess I am used to viewing components as no more than their props. May I ask why do you need those components exactly?